# `In instantiation of [template class] [member] is protected [. . .] [public member] is inaccessible'

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I encounter the following error when attempting to instantiate a class of type `SystemBody` or `AcceleratedBody`:

```
error: 'bool InitializationChecker::is_initialized_' is protected
```

Indeed, `is_initialized_` *is* `protected`.

```
class InitializationChecker {
 [. . .]
 protected:
  bool is_initialized_;
};
```

`is_initialized_` is inherited from `InitializationChecker` through several other classes.

```
InitializationChecker
           ^
           |
MultipleInitializationChecker
  ^
  |
Body
  ^
  |
AcceleratedBody
     ^
     |
SystemBody
```

`Body` is declared as such:

```
template<typename Type> class Body : public MultipleInitializationChecker {
  using MultipleInitializationChecker::is_initialized_;
 public:
  Body() {
    this->is_initialized_ = false;
  }
  Body(const Scalar<Type> mass__,
       const CartesianVector<Type> position__,
       const CartesianVector<Type> velocity__)
      : mass_(mass__),
        position_(position__),
        velocity_(velocity__) {
          this->is_initialized_ = true;
  }
  [. . .]
  Scalar<Type> mass_;
  CartesianVector<Type> position_;
  CartesianVector<Type> velocity_;
};
```

I also encounter another problem: some of the members of `SystemBody` are inaccessible. For example:

```
error: 'Scalar<double> Body<double>::mass_' is inaccessible
```

is output when I try to do something like the following:

```
SystemBody<double> system_body;
std::cout << system_body.mass_.value();
```

even though `SystemBody` only adds one irrelevant private member and `AcceleratedBody` is declared as such:

```
template<typename Type> class AcceleratedBody : public Body<Type> {
  using Body<Type>::is_initialized_;
  using Body<Type>::mass_;
  using Body<Type>::position_;
  using Body<Type>::velocity_;
 public:
  AcceleratedBody() : Body<Type>::Body() {}
  AcceleratedBody(const Scalar<Type> mass__,
                  const CartesianVector<Type> position__,
                  const CartesianVector<Type> velocity__,
                  const CartesianVector<Type> acceleration__)
      : Body<Type>::Body(mass__, position__, velocity__),
        acceleration_(acceleration__) {}
  [. . .]
  CartesianVector<Type> acceleration_;
};
```

Note that `mass_`, `position_`, and `velocity_` are all declared publicly in `Body`.

Comment: Nail this to a point of interest please (Where exactly the error message occurs and why you don't expect it).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would it have been best to post simple code representative of my classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using MultipleInitializationChecker::is_initialized_;` Doing this in a private region of the class makes it private. You don't even need that line. What do you think it does?

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about the placement of those! It did not strike me which access modifier they were placed in would affect the access of the variable they forwarded. Everything works now! (I will accept your answer in a few minutes once the time limit expires.)